# only duplicate records filtered by created Mysql Query

Tags: mysql, duplicates, greatest-n-per-group

Am trying to fetching records using select query with where clause, id duplicate records are presented then i want to filtered it by `createdAt` field.

while am running the below query and getting the result like this :

```
select * from security_development.user_requests
where
fully_approved = 1 and user_request_role=4
```

Please find the results

```
createdAt           User_request_name fully_approved user_request_role
2019-02-22 18:57:08  dealerAdmin        1               4
2019-02-24 08:57:08  ask1               1               4
2019-02-25 12:20:22  dealerAdmin        1               4
```

If i try to avoid only the duplicate `User_request_name` by using `max(creaTed_at)` as sub query,

```
select * from security_development.user_requests
where fully_approved =1 and user_request_role=4
created_at = 
(select max(creaTed_at) from security_development.user_requests group by user_request_name having count(user_request_name) > 1 )
```

then am getting the below result

```
createdAt           User_request_name fully_approved user_request_role
2019-02-25 12:20:22  dealerAdmin        1               4
```

But am expecting the below results

```
createdAt           User_request_name fully_approved user_request_role
2019-02-24 08:57:08  ask1               1               4
2019-02-25 12:20:22  dealerAdmin        1               4
```

Comment: what happens if you have the same `createdAt` for two `user_request_name`s? To retreve a within group maximum, look at this [SQL pattern](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=104)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery

```
select t1.* from security_development.user_requests t1
where
fully_approved = 1 and user_request_role=4
and createdAt=( select max(createdAt) 
              from security_development.user_requests t2
                where t1.User_request_name=t2.User_request_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the same as the question:

To delete existing duplicates keeping the latest:

```
DELETE t1 FROM user_requests t1
INNER JOIN user_requests t2 
WHERE t1.createdAt < t2.createdAt AND t1.user_request_name = t2.user_request_name
```

To prevent duplicate `User_request_name` being inserted:

```
Alter table user_requests
add unique key (User_request_name);
```